# Jquery/Javascript memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I have a web application which show chart and update chart status each 10 seconds.

HTML is:

```
<div id="hoze-bar-chart"></div>
```

JS for drawing chart:

```
var handleStackedChart = function() {
  "use strict";

  function v(e, t, n) {
    $('<div id="tooltip" class="flot-tooltip">' + n + "</div>").css({
      top: t,
      left: e + 35
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
  }
  var e = displaycount.e;
  var n = displaycount.n;
  var h = displaycount.h;

  var p = {
    xaxis: {
      tickColor: "transparent",
      ticks: h
    },
    yaxis: {
      tickColor: "#ddd",
      ticksLength: 10
    },
    grid: {
      hoverable: !0,
      tickColor: "#ccc",
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"
    },
    series: {
      stack: null,
      lines: {
        show: !1,
        fill: !1,
        steps: !1
      },
      bars: {
        show: !0,
        barWidth: .5,
        align: "center",
        fillColor: null
      },
      highlightColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"
    },
    legend: {
      show: !0,
      labelBoxBorderColor: "#ccc",
      position: "ne",
      noColumns: 1
    }
  };
  var d = [{
    data: e,
    color: green,
    label: displaycount.totalTitle,
    bars: {
      fillColor: green
    }
  }, {
    data: n,
    color: red,
    label: displaycount.offlineTitle,
    bars: {
      fillColor: red
    }
  }];

  $.plot("#hoze-bar-chart", d, p);

  var m = null;
  var g = null;
  $("#hoze-bar-chart").bind("plothover", function(e, t, n) {
    if (n) {
      if ($(document).width() >= 1024 && $(document).width() < 1680)
        $("#hoze-bar-chart .flot-x-axis .flot-tick-label:eq(" + n.dataIndex + ")").show();

      var r = n.datapoint[1] - n.datapoint[2];
      if (m != n.series.label || r != g) {
        m = n.series.label;
        g = r;

        if ($(document).width() >= 1024 && $(document).width() < 1680)
          $("#hoze-bar-chart .flot-x-axis .flot-tick-label:eq(" + n.dataIndex + ")").hide();

        $("#tooltip").remove();
        v(n.pageX, n.pageY, r + " " + n.series.label);
      }

      //Free Memory
      r = null;

    } else {
      if ($(document).width() >= 1024 && $(document).width() < 1680)
        $("#hoze-bar-chart .flot-x-axis .flot-tick-label").hide();
      $("#tooltip").remove();
    }
  })

  //Free Memory
  e = null;
  n = null;
  h = null;
  displaycount.e = null;
  displaycount.n = null;
  displaycount.h = null;
  displaycount.totalTitle = null;
  displaycount.offlineTitle = null;
  p = null;
  d = null;
  m = null;
  g = null
};
```

JS for call chart function first and call that each 10 seconds:

```
var Dashboard = function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        init: function() {
            handleStackedChart();
            handleLiveUpdatedChart();
        }
    }
}()

var handleLiveUpdatedChart = function() {
    "use strict";
    var listenerAjaxRequest = {};
    listenerAjaxRequest.readyState = 4;
    function e() {
        if( listenerAjaxRequest.readyState != 1)
        {
            listenerAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "PHP_FILE_PATH",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    displaycount.h = response.displyCountArray.titleData;
                    displaycount.e = response.displyCountArray.onlineData;
                    displaycount.n = response.displyCountArray.offlineData;
                    handleStackedChart();

                    displaycount.h = null;
                    displaycount.e = null;
                    displaycount.n = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

First time which i run this website browser get 235MB memory but after 10 minutes i see browser get 255MB memory and this page is open 12 hours each day and browser crash because i have 10 chart on page and each 10 minutes browser get 100MB memory.

If i comment running handleLiveUpdatedChart() this issue will solve but i need to update data regularly.

At this time i need to know how i can handle memory and solve this issue.

Comment: How do you call it each 10 seconds?

Comment: So you're re-binding a new `plothover` listener every ten seconds? No wonder they accumulate memory

Comment: @A.Wolff  I updated question.

Comment: At least don't use interval but a timeout call recursively once any pending ajax request has completed, see http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/  And don't bind over and over again event/plugin of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that you can do:

1. Define the `v` function outside of the `handleStackedChart` function. You don't have to re-define it on each function call. And if the `v` function is called many times, for generating an element, use DOM APIs instead of using jQuery. Note that function calls are expensive.
2. Define the `p` object outside of the `handleStackedChart` function and only update it's variable properties, e.g.: `p.xaxis.ticks = h;`
3. You are currently *adding* a new listener to the `#hoze-bar-chart` on each `handleStackedChart` call. When the event is fired all of the event listeners of the element are called and this alone can crash the browser. Also, you can cache the result of `$(document).width()` and reuse it instead of calling the function again and again.
4. Instead of using an interval use the `setTimeout` function. When the request is done and chart is redrawn, set a new timeout.

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you please send an example about: "for generating an element, use DOM APIs instead of using jQuery"

Comment: Khahesh mikonam! You can use [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for creating the element. Generating all the elements at once is another option that can improve the performance.